# Mixin more than one template in a dojo widget

Tags: javascript, templates, dojo

I wanted to mixin templates in a dojo widget same as the way it is mentioned in [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html), but was not able to mix in more than one template. To achieve this I have tried mixing in dom constructed out of templated string(template to be mixed in) using [lang.mixin](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html), however that is not helpful as it does not mix in the attach points and attach events. Please suggest if there is any other way to mix in two templates in a single widget.

Actual scenario: I have to mixin templates for a list container and list item in a widget.

Comment: Define "mixin two templates" - as in, how exactly do you expect the templates to be combined?  Can you give examples of what you tried, and/or an example of what the 2 templates look like vs. what you expect the end result to be?

Comment: It sounds like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a mixin is. To put it simply, it's combining two Javascript objects' variables together. lang.mixin({a:'a'},{b:'b',c:'c'}) returns {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'} ... it doesn't work with strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Dojo/HTML to write a bit of Html. It is similar to DomConstruct and easier for a long Html as you can directly write your elements properties into a simple variable.

```
require(["dojo/html", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/form/NumberTextBox","dojo/domReady!"], 
function(html, dom, on){
    on(dom.byId("setContent"), "click", function(){
        html.set(dom.byId("content"), '<div class="myClass">'
            + '<ul id="myId">'
                + '<li> li 1 </li>'
                + '<li> li 2 </li>'
                + '<li> li 3 </li>'
            + '</ul>'
            + '<input type="inputText" />'
        + '</div>',
      {
        parseContent: true
      });
  });
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/html.html

Answer (score 0):

In Dojo, it's 1:1 template per widget using the _TemplatedMixin. A single widget cannot have multiple templates.

What is sounds like you're trying to do is have a list item widget **inside of** a list container widget. You want two widgets, not one!

MyListWidget.html:

```
<ul></ul>
```

MyListItemWidget.html:

```
<li>${itemContent}</li>
```

Dojo 1.7+:

```
define("MyListItemWidget", [
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dojo/text!./templates/MyListItemWidget.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {
  return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
    templateString: template,
    postCreate: function() {
      // Do your thing.
    }
  });
});

define("MyListWidget", [
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dojo/text!./templates/MyListWidget.html",
"MyListItemWidget"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template, MyListItemWidget) {
  return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
    templateString: template,
    postCreate: function() {
      new ListItemWidget({itemContent:"Hello"}).placeAt(this.domNode);
      new ListItemWidget({itemContent:"World"}).placeAt(this.domNode);
    }
  });
});

require(["MyListWidget", "dojo/domReady!"], function(MyListWidget) {
  new MyListWidget().placeAt('wherever');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I opted to do the same now, but I still wanted to know if there is any other way to mixin a small additional template(if any) along with the main template in a single widget.

Comment: You would have to handle that manually. You can use dojo/dom-construct's toDom method to create a node from a string of HTML.

Comment: I tried that, as I have explained earlier it's attach points and attach events are missing.

Comment: You could try combining two template strings together in the widget's constructor then setting that result to the templateString. Also, maybe using dojox/dtl/_Templated instead of dijit/_TemplatedMixin will suit your needs better. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.